# I have an error with my TCP nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna make an tcp server with nodejs . When i start the server in the terminal it says nothing, and when i start the client the client gets the message but in the server terminal, it prints:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at Socket.onerror (internal/streams/readable.js:760:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

When i start the client again, the server is still running, i needed to stop the server using killall node.
How can i fix this error.

**Server:**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Connected to server !\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

**Client**:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: It prints...the source code? Question isn't clear.

Comment: I think you forgot to add important details in the question @Blockzii . Read through it again and edit it.

Comment: `client.on('data',` won't receive the full response from the server, if you close the connection early you would get errors like ECONNRESET